# How to set variables for bash script using packer?

Tags: bash, packer

I want to achive following:

1. Create Linux VPN server image with Packer
2. Pull config files from S3 bucket and configure StrongSwan, BGPD, keepalive etc

The troubles starts with pulling files from S3 bucket, where i need to set variable in order for bash script to connect to AWS and transfer the mentioned files.

Here is packer code:

```
{
    "variables": {
      "aws_access_key": "{{env `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`}}",
      "aws_secret_key": "{{env `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}",
      "aws_default_region": "{{env `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`}}",
      "aws_source_ami": "{{env `AWS_SOURCE_AMI`}}",
      "aws_ssh_user": "{{env `AWS_SSH_USER`}}",
      "script_aws_access": "{{env `SCRIPT_AWS_ACCESS_KEY`}}",
      "script_aws_secret_access": "{{env `SCRIPT_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}"
    },
    "builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
      "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
      "region": "eu-west-1",
      "vpc_id": "vpc-0816d88cdecb1438a",
      "subnet_id": "subnet-07e30b1ad80f0c4a8",
      "security_group_id": "sg-098ff42f1bdaf7183",
      "associate_public_ip_address": "true",
      "instance_type": "t2.micro",
      "ami_name": "myLinuxPackerImage",
      "source_ami": "ami-0ff760d16d9497662",
      "ssh_username": "{{user `aws_ssh_user`}}"
      }
     ],

  "provisioners": [
    {
        "type": "file",
        "source": "./welcome.txt",
        "destination": "/home/centos/"
    },
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "inline":[
            "ls -al /home/centos",
            "cat /home/centos/welcome.txt",
            "sleep 30",
            "sudo yum update -y"
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "script": "./example.sh",
        "environment_vars": [
          "AWS_ACCESS_KEY={{user `script_aws_access`}}",
          "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY={{user `script_aws_secret_access`}}"
        ],    
        "pause_before": "10s"
    }
]
}
```

Environment variables:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="mykey"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="mysecret"
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="eu-west-1"
export AWS_SOURCE_AMI="ami-0ff760d16d9497662"
export AWS_SSH_USER="centos"
export SCRIPT_AWS_ACCESS_KEY="my-SCRIPT-key"
export SCRIPT_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="my-secret-SCRIPT-key"
```

Actual bash script (example.sh) for provisioner:

```
#!/bin/bash
AWS_ACCESS_KEY=${1}
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${2}
sudo yum install epel-release -y 
sudo yum install nano wget htop telnet strongswan quagga iptables-services iptables python-pip -y 
sudo systemctl stop firewalld && systemctl disable firewalld  
sudo systemctl enable iptables && systemctl start iptables 
sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc 
sh -c 'echo -e "[azure-cli]\nname=Azure CLI\nbaseurl=https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/azure-cli\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc" > /etc/yum.repos.d/azure-cli.repo'
sudo yum install azure-cli -y
sudo yum update -y && easy_install pip
sudo pip install awscli
sudo yum install keepalived -y && sudo systemctl enable keepalived
sudo useradd keepalived_script 
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1

# Copy BGPD files

aws s3 cp --recursive  s3://<s3-url>/azure_vpn_server_primary/quagga/ /etc/quagga/

#Copy StrongSwan files

aws s3 cp --recursive  s3://<s3-url>/azure_vpn_server_primary/strongswan/ /etc/strongswan/

# In Azure, the instance should have IP Forwarding enabled on its network interface

# Copy keepalived files

aws s3 cp --recursive  s3://<s3-url>/azure_vpn_server_primary/keepalived/ /etc/keepalived/
```

ERROR:

```
amazon-ebs: Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/keepalived.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/keepalived.service.
    amazon-ebs: fatal error: An error occurred (AuthorizationHeaderMalformed) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The authorization header is malformed; a non-empty Access Key (AKID) must be provided in the credential.
    amazon-ebs: fatal error: An error occurred (AuthorizationHeaderMalformed) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The authorization header is malformed; a non-empty Access Key (AKID) must be provided in the credential.
```

Answer (score 2):

Found solution.

Had to remove >

AWS_ACCESS_KEY=${1}
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${2}

from bash script.
Works now!